# WCF: How do I check server is accessible?

Tags: .net, wcf, client-server

I have WCF server and WCF client. When a new version of client is deployed I want to check that it's ready to run so I have to check if server is online.

I don't want to do any real server calls (because calls can change production data) or create empty {...} "Test" methods on server that do nothing.

Is it possible to check that WCF server endpoint is present and listens to connections without method calls?

I tried:

```
factory = new ChannelFactory<IServer>())
factory.CreateChannel();
```

and

```
factory = new ChannelFactory<IServer>())
factory.Open();
```

but there are no exceptions if server is offline. 
How should I check server presence without server method call?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way to check that an endpoint is listening without making a call to it. There are all kinds of reasons why a client may not be able to connect to an endpoint, so the only way of being really sure is by making the call. Also remember that endpoints may become inaccessible at any moment, so clients need to be prepared for that.

So there are two options open to you:

1. In the past, I've added a Ping method on my service, that simply returns true. But that only tells you that the service is available at that moment.
2. As a more reliable mechanism, I would probably just catch the relevant WCF exception on each service call (EndpointNotFoundException IIRC) and deduce the failure from that. This allows you to tolerate faults that may occur over time - after the initial connection, for example.

Comment: @Andrew, Just updated my answer - reason was that you'd need to keep Pinging to be sure the service was still up. Far easier just to try making the call and see if it succeeds.

Comment: +1 Exactly - even having a Ping method on your service **cannot guarantee** that the next service call in a fraction of a second will succeed - so it really doesn't tell you anything at all... just call the service and be prepared to handle any possible exception that might occur!

Comment: Ok, thank you everybody, but all I need just to check that server is online once after client deploy :)